# Using wxFormbuilder to Create GUI and Tab_Traversal is not working

Tags: tabs, traversal, wxformbuilder

I am creating a simple GUI application using wxFormbuilder. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTAt6.png)

I want it to have Tab Traversal and I have that checked on the "Frame" properties.  I read on another thread here that I need to have a "Panel" as a child of the "Frame," but the wxFormbuilder will not let me create a Panel as a child of the Frame.  It only puts it on the same hierarchical level.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m213B.png)
My GUI does not allow jumping between textboxes nor does it move after an "Enter" command.  I am imagining that there is something obvious that I am missing.

Comment: Adding wxpanel at the bottom of your controls enables Tab_Traversal to work by default on windows

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here.

https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=42487

[WxFormbuilder correct layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2xbA.png)

edit. 
Try installing the 3.5 beta version instead of 3.5.1rc1
Stackoverflow wont let me post the 2nd link because i dont have enough rep points.

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me the same problem.

try to use wxDialog instead of the wxFrame this will solve the problem for you.